Unable to play same item in Media Recyclerview
I have media items which are mp3 in recyclerview mp3 are stored in raw. Everything is right but when I try to play the same item again it won't play. Here is how it goes:

Play any item from recyclerview - it play
Stop same item - it stops but when stopping there is some issue regarding the state of mediaPlayer for this purpose logs are attached.
When clicked same item to play - it dont play, logs error are attached for this as well.

there are three methods that i am calling in on click of the button.
holder.musicPlay.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  if (currentPlayingPosition == holder.getAdapterPosition()) {
                // Toggle playback for the currently playing item
                handleTogglePlayback(holder);
            } else {
                // Stop and release the previous MediaPlayer if it's not null
                releaseMediaPlayer();

                // Initialize a new MediaPlayer for the selected item
                initializeMediaPlayer(holder, itemModel);
            }
        });


private void handleTogglePlayback(ViewHolder holder) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    holder.musicPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                    if (onMusicEventListener != null) {
                        onMusicEventListener.onMusicStop();
                    }
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    holder.musicPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    if (onMusicEventListener != null) {
                        onMusicEventListener.onMusicStart(list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getMusicName(), mediaPlayer);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("CategoryItemAdapter", "IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaPlayer();
            }
        }
    }
    
 private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("CategoryItemAdapter", "Error stopping MediaPlayer: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }
    
private void initializeMediaPlayer(ViewHolder holder, CategoryItemModel itemModel) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, itemModel.getMusicSource());
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> {
                    holder.musicPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                    if (onMusicEventListener != null) {
                        onMusicEventListener.onMusicStop();
                    }
                    currentPlayingPosition = -1;
                });

                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener((mp, what, extra) -> {
                    Log.e("CategoryItemAdapter", "MediaPlayer error: " + what + ", " + extra);
                    return true;
                });

                mediaPlayer.start();
                holder.musicPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

                if (onMusicEventListener != null) {
                    onMusicEventListener.onMusicStart(itemModel.getMusicName(), mediaPlayer);
                }

                if (currentPlayingViewHolder != null) {
                    currentPlayingViewHolder.musicPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                }

                currentPlayingViewHolder = holder;
                currentPlayingPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CategoryItemAdapter", "Error initializing MediaPlayer: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    }

on stoppping the item from musicPlay these are logs that i get
MediaPlayer            W  mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
chatty                 I  uid=10310(com.app.sleepy) identical 1 line
MediaPlayer            W  mediaplayer went away with unhandled events

on clicking the musicPlay to play that item again, i cant play the same item again and it shows these errors
CategoryItemAdapter     E  IllegalStateException: null
CategoryItemAdapter     E  Error stopping MediaPlayer: null
MediaPlayer             V  resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
MediaPlayer             V  cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null

I tried this for reseting the state of the mediaplayer but it doesnot work for me. please suggest the soultion to this problem.
mediaPlayer.reset() 

before
mediaPlayer.release()

but error occured here
